# Document modifications remembered by Firefox when back button pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

When a form is submitted I show a loading animation and disable the button. Unfortunately, when I click the back button, Firefox still shows the loading image and the button is still disabled. This does not happen in Chrome. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#go').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#loading').replaceWith('<img id="loading" src="/static/images/loading.gif" style="display:none; vertical-align:middle" />');

    $('#go').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#go').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#loading').show();
        $('#go_form').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Just a theory, but if you're using POST, could that cause the data to be resubmitted, and hence, your loading image showing again?

Comment: Highly unlikely, as the form is submitted in an `onclick`, which the browser doesn't perform automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox uses in-memory caching for entire web pages, including their JavaScript state, within a browser session. Going backwards and forwards between visited pages requires no page loading. This feature makes page navigation very fast.

In order to detect this, use the `pageshow` event. The event will have a property called `persisted` which will be true if you are navigating through the cache. If you see this state, you can reset the state of your page.

Comment: I can't find any documentation for the pageshow event, it doesn't seem to exist in jQuery. How do I catch it?

Comment: For those of you still wondering, @shaurz was able to use `$(window).bind('pageshow', function() { /* code to reset elements */ });`.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to different cache mechanisms in Chrome and Firefox. A simple fix would be to hide the loading image in the `onunload` event.

Comment: This isn't really a fix, because as soon as you use an unload event you disable the page cache, slowing down the browser.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for pointing that out. Although the logic of that implementation decision eludes me entirely.